# DisplayMode.equals(DisplayMode dm) Confusion

Tags: java, fullscreen, displaymode

So, I'm making a fullscreen application and ran across something weird.

The Method DisplayMode.equals(DisplayMode dm) is overridden but I don't think it's implemented quite right. The following code prints false to the console:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    DisplayMode mode = new (1,2,16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    System.out.println(mode.equals(new DisplayMode(1, 2, 16, 60)));
}
```

If the display modes are the same save for their refresh rates, and one of them is unknown, then I think they should be equal. Why is that not the case, and can someone suggest a workaround for me to use? Also, why do the online the Java Docs show that there are two overloaded versions of the .equals() method, one with a DisplayMode Object and one with a Java.Lang.Object Object? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/DisplayMode.html

Answer (score 0):

The difference I believe is that in the first case, you're saying "I know for a fact that the refresh rate is unknown" and in the second case you're saying "I know for a fact that the refresh rate is 60".

The implementation from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/awt/DisplayMode.java#DisplayMode.equals%28java.awt.DisplayMode%29) shows the following:

```
public boolean equals(DisplayMode dm) {
    if (dm == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return (getHeight() == dm.getHeight()
         && getWidth() == dm.getWidth()
         && getBitDepth() == dm.getBitDepth()
         && getRefreshRate() == dm.getRefreshRate());
}
```

you can see that it compares the value of the refresh rate at the bottom.

[java.awt.DisplayMode#REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/awt/DisplayMode.java#DisplayMode.0REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN) is defined as `0`.

As for the second question, about why that overload the `equals` method, it allows the code to separated and focus on only the part it cares about. For example, if it were not overloaded, the `equals` method would look like

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (obj instanceof DisplayMode) {
        DisplayMode dm = (DisplayMode) obj;

        return (getHeight() == dm.getHeight()
             && getWidth() == dm.getWidth()
             && getBitDepth() == dm.getBitDepth()
             && getRefreshRate() == dm.getRefreshRate());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a .equals() method overridden for this object, but not the many dozens of other objects in the Java Libraries?

Comment: @AviCaspe I'm not certain of the answer. There may be a performance consideration to it. At compile time, the compiler is able to tell which exact method to call in this case; so if you wanted to compare two `DisplayMode` objects, you would save a couple of instructions by calling the one taking a `DisplayMode` as an argument, instead of the one taking an `Object`. Another thing to consider is that annotations didn't exist when this class was added, so you couldn't use `@Override` which may have something to do with it.